# Wrong rendering of thousands separator with custom font in itext

Tags: pdf, fonts, itext, itext7, separator

I have a rendering issue since I upgraded to iText 7.2 (from 7.1.7) with a custom font.

The thousand separator is not rendered correctly.

[With iText 7.1.7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oubex.png)

[With iText 7.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8RMd.png)

```cs
tableArticles.AddCell(new Cell(1, 2)
                .Add(new Paragraph($"{bonCommande.Total:C}")
                    .SetFontSize(14)
                    .SetBold()
                    .SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.RIGHT)
                    .SetFixedLeading(LeadingSize))
                .SetBorder(new SolidBorder(1))
                .SetVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE)
                .SetPadding(5));
```

I tried to update the font by drawing something for unicode char arabic thousands separator (U+066C) but without success.

I'm from Belgium and use "fr-BE".

Thanks for any help.

EDIT :
Here is some code example with the font and pdfs examples.
[WeTransfer Link To PDFs and Font](https://www.swisstransfer.com/d/69d4f4c1-cf2b-4a51-a841-493237b3164f)

```cs
 public class PdfCurrencyModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly IPdfCurrencyService _pdfCurrencyService;

        public PdfCurrencyModel(IPdfCurrencyService pdfCurrencyService)
        {
            _pdfCurrencyService = pdfCurrencyService;
        }
        public IActionResult OnGetAsync()
        {
            //var stream =  _pdfCurrencyService.GetPDFMemoryStream();
            //return File(stream, MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf, "Values.pdf");

            var bytesArray =  _pdfCurrencyService.GetPDFBytesArray();
            return new FileContentResult(bytesArray, MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf);
        }
    }
public interface IPdfCurrencyService
    {
        public MemoryStream GetPDFMemoryStream();
        public byte[] GetPDFBytesArray();
    }

    public class PdfCurrencyService : IPdfCurrencyService
    {
        public MemoryStream GetPDFMemoryStream()
        {
            // Fonts
            var fontTexte = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(FontConstants.BrownBold,
                PdfFontFactory.EmbeddingStrategy.FORCE_EMBEDDED);

            // Initialisation
            var ms = new MemoryStream();

            // Initialize PDF writer
            var writer = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfWriter(ms);
            writer.SetCloseStream(false);

            // Initialize PDF document
            var pdfDoc = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument(writer);

            // Initialize document
            var document = new Document(pdfDoc, iText.Kernel.Geom.PageSize.A4)
                .SetFont(fontTexte).SetFontSize(10);

            // Values
            for (var i = 1000; i <= 2000; i += 100)
                document.Add(new Paragraph(i.ToString("C")));

            // Close document
            document.Close();

            //ms.Flush();
            ms.Position = 0;

            return ms;
        }

        public byte[] GetPDFBytesArray()
        {
            return GetPDFMemoryStream().ToArray();
        }
    }
```

EDIT 2 : I created a simple web app with the problem
[Link to project](https://www.swisstransfer.com/d/c5444632-0afb-4f36-ad57-2c56bba1d8e6)

Comment: In your screen shots it looks like there used to be _no_ thousands separator but there is one now. But as it's not iText that converts the total to a string, it appears that more changes happened in your code than merely the iText update, it looks like `$"{bonCommande.Total:C}"` now evaluates differently than it used to. You might want to investigate that first...

Comment: I assure you that the only change I made was to update iText. I tried to rollback and update multiples times and I only have this problem with 7.2 version.

Comment: Can you share example PDFs for analysis?

Comment: @mkl I update my original post and provide some code with the pdfs

Comment: I'm sorry but I cannot reproduce the issue. I get "1.000,00 €" for the "fr-BE" culture, no matter whether it's iText 7.1.17, 7.2.0, or 7.2.1. And your code does not compile with the version 7.1.7 you mention as `PdfFontFactory.EmbeddingStrategy` did not exist yet in that version.

Comment: There are a number of dependencies updated between iText 7.1.7 (or even 7.1.17) and iText 7.2.1. Could it be that those dependencies are not updated in your project somehow and your observation occurs due to non-matching component versions?

Comment: I created a simple project that you can download. Thanks for your investigation.

Comment: Unfortunately that project requires IIS and all that ASP stuff to be installed which I don't intend to activate here. Have you tried running your code as a simple command line application?

Answer (score 0):

When using the "fr-BE" culture this line:

```
1000.ToString("C")
```

evaluates to:

```
1.000,00 €
```

It seems that iText does some processing with the "." (dot) because neither files are correct.

Seems that 7.2.1 changed the way the fonts are handled. 7.1.7 created a simple WinAnsi font while 7.2.1 creates a Type0 font.

7.1.7 does not write at all the dot in the PDF file:

```
BT
/F1 10 Tf
36 787.93 Td
(1000,00 €)Tj
ET
```

7.2.1 writes <0000> for the dot GID (instead of <0073>) in the PDF file (spaces in string added by me to emphasize each GID):

```
BT
/F1 10 Tf
36 787.93 Td
<0093 0000 00a2 00a2 00a2 0080 00a2 00a2 0074 00e1>Tj
ET
```

Comment: How did you get the code to run with iText 7.1.7? The `enum PdfFontFactory.EmbeddingStrategy` used in the OP's code did not yet exist in that version...

Comment: I did not run the code, I looked inside the PDF files to see how the fonts are defined

Comment: Maybe it's my custom font that doesn't have the thousand separator drawed.

Comment: @JohnValdevit The thousands separator in fr-BE according to iPDFdev's initial test appears to be the regular period, and that appears to be in your font. Also if iText would have dropped periods when drawing text in WinAnsiEncoding fonts in some 7.1.x versions, that would have given rise to a lot of issues here and elsewhere. So in essence neither your iText 7.1.x results nor your iText 7.2.x results appear to be reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to make it work.
It appears that iText use U+202F (NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE) as thousands separator in 7.2.x versions but it was not the case before.

My font didn't have something specified so it rendered a square.
I copy/paste from U+0020 which is "SPACE" and I don't have any problem anymore.

In fr-BE and fr-FR the thousands separator is a blank space and not an dot.

```cs
var separator = new CultureInfo("fr-BE", false)
            .NumberFormat
            .CurrencyGroupSeparator;

Debug.WriteLine($"Currency Group Separator for fr-BE is {(int)separator[0]}");
Debug.WriteLine($"As HEX {((int)separator[0]).ToString("X")}");

// Currency Group Separator for fr-BE is 8239
//As HEX 202F
```

Thanks anyone for your time.

Comment: When I run your code I get "Currency Group Separator for fr-BE is 46
As HEX 2E"...